# Using Ninject to find appropriate CommandHandler

Tags: c#, generics, ninject

I'm trying to use Azure Message Queues with a Commands pattern similar to that used in CQRS.

Here is an example command:

```
public class SetZoneModeCommand : ICommand
{
    public string GatewayId { get; set; }

    public string ReceiverId { get; set; }

    public int ChannelNumber { get; set; }

    public HeatingMode Mode { get; set; }
}
```

Here is its Handler

```
public class SetZoneModeCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SetZoneModeCommand>
{
    private readonly IDatabaseContext _databaseContext;

    public SetZoneModeCommandHandler(IDatabaseContext databaseContext)
    {
        _databaseContext = databaseContext;
    }

    public RequestStatus Execute(SetZoneModeCommand command)
    {
        if (command == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("command");
        }
        var result = new RequestStatus();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm using Ninject in a Worker Role with this configuration:

```
_kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("Business.dll")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .BindDefaultInterface());
```

This works fine and the dependencies are being injected.

I have a QueuedCommand object which is serialised using JSON and this is placed on the Azure Message Queue:

```
public class QueuedCommand
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public object Command { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }

    public int AddedByUserId { get; set; }

    public int RetryCount { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the (unoptimised) code which tries to deserialise the QueueCommand and process it:

```
var queuedCommand = (QueuedCommand)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueuedCommand>(message.AsString);
            var commandInterface = typeof(ICommand);

            var commandType = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                where (commandInterface.IsAssignableFrom(type)) && (commandInterface != type)
                      && type.FullName == queuedCommand.ClassName
                select type).FirstOrDefault();

var o = (JObject) queuedCommand.Command;
                var command = (ICommand)o.ToObject(commandType);
                var result = _commandDispatcher.Dispatch(command);
```

This all works fine and if I debug, the command object passed to the dispatcher is of the correct type and is populated with the expected values.

The CommandDispatcher should find the concrete implementation of the CommandHandler for the Command it was given. My problem is that it is not and I am getting an error about there being no Bindings for ICommandHandler.

If I replace the cast from ICommand to cast to SetZoneModeCommand then it works as expected. This is obviously unacceptable and I thought it wouldn't be too difficult to cast if I had an Object and a fully qualified class name.

```
public interface ICommandDispatcher
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispatches a command to its handler
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TParameter">Command Type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="command">The command to be passed to the handler</param>
    RequestStatus Dispatch<TParameter>(TParameter command) where TParameter : ICommand;
}

public CommandDispatcher(IKernel kernel)
    {
        if (kernel == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("kernel");
        }
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public RequestStatus Dispatch<TParameter>(TParameter command) where TParameter : ICommand
    {
        var handler = _kernel.Get<ICommandHandler<TParameter>>();
        return handler.Execute(command);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write the same code you posted a bit differently "formatted":

```
ICommand command = (ICommand)o.ToObject(commandType);
RequestStatus result = _commandDispatcher.Dispatch<ICommand>(command);
```

so instead of calling `ICommandDispatcher.Dispatch<commandType>(command)` you're calling it with the type parameter `ICommand`. You need to use reflection to select the correct type parameters for `Dispatch<TParameter>(TParameter command)`:

---

```
object command = o.ToObject(commandType);

MethodInfo dispatchMethod = GetMethod<ICommand>(c => _commandDispatcher.Dispatch(c))
    .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
    .MakeGenericMethod(commandType);

RequestStatus result = (RequestStatus)dispatchMethod.Invoke(
    _commandDispatcher,
    new object[] { command });


public static MethodInfo GetMethod<T1>(Expression<Action<T1>> methodSelector)
{
    return GetMethodInfo(methodSelector);
}

private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(LambdaExpression methodSelector)
{
    if (methodSelector == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("methodSelector");
    }
    if (methodSelector.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.Call)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            "methodSelector", 
            "Specified expression does is not a method call expression.");
    }

    var callExpression = (MethodCallExpression)methodSelector.Body;
    return callExpression.Method;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply. I knew I had to make use of MakeGenericMethod but wasn't sure how. I have change my code to match your suggestion but am now getting the error: "The type arguments for method 'CommandProcessor.GetMethod<T1>(Expression<Action<T1>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: @JohnMc sorry, i've typed most of the code by memory. Mistake should now be fixed: `GetMethod<ICommand>(c => _commandDispatcher.Dispatch(c))`. Hope there's not more.

Comment: Haven't tested it yet but it's compiling now. Thank you, I'd give you a hundred +1's if I could!